# Creating pivot table from SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, ssrs-2012

I have a SQL query that returns the following result:

[image]

The data comes from a view that is returning a hotel stay survey data. If you see the column `Question` contains 5 different values that are repeated for each report number. So there are 5 separate entries in `Question` for each report number. The column `Answer` has the values for each entry in column. I am trying to create a report where each of these entries in `Question` column will be transformed into 5 separate columns and the values will be the entries from `Answer` like below:

[image]

I searched for viable solution as I am not very familiar with SQL and learned about pivot tables and how the groups can be transformed into columns using pivot tables. But I am not able to understand how do I create one.

I found some explanation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) and [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-performance-analytics-and-reporting/page/use/reporting/concept/create-pivot-report-rb.html) but both seems like configuration details for report builder. Not sure how to do that using sql query.

Any help will be great!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  All you need to do is copy the code, replace it with your table name and column names.  Then see how it goes.  If it doesn't work, post the code here.  If you haven't done that, get to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below, i think there is column of values which contain city,hotel .. values

```
select * from 
(
select * from query
) src
pivot
 (max(values) for Question in ([City],[Hotel],[Rating],[Comments],[TransportationMode])
 ) pvt
```

Comment: Yes I am sorry for not putting that column. There is a column for values of city, ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t.ReportNumber, t.Datecreated, t.Name, p.City, p.Hotel, p.Rating,
 p.Comments, p.TransportationMode
 FROM tablename t
 PIVOT (MAX(Datecreated)
 FOR Question IN ([City], [Hotel], [Rating], [Comments], [TransportationMode])) AS P
```

Comment: I get an error saying "the multi-part identifier cannot be bound" for columns t.ReportNumber, t.Datecreated, t.Name.

Comment: @Naphstor Debugging is part of programmer's job.  You are given a solution.  When you get the error, and the error is pretty clear, you debug.  Are there columns `ReportNumber`, `DateCreated`, and `Name` on your table `tablename`?  If not, then there is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output with conditional aggregation:

```
declare @tmp table(
    ReportNumber int, 
    Datecreated  date, 
    Name         varchar(50), 
    Question     varchar(50),
    Answer       varchar(50) 
)

insert into @tmp values 
 (123, '2018-04-24', 'Shane', 'City'               ,'Dallas')
,(123, '2018-04-24', 'Shane', 'Hotel'              ,'Marriott')
,(123, '2018-04-24', 'Shane', 'Rating'             ,'Green')
,(123, '2018-04-24', 'Shane', 'Comments'           ,'Very Good')
,(123, '2018-04-24', 'Shane', 'TransportationMode' ,'Van')
,(124, '2018-04-24', 'Ralph', 'Hotel'              ,'Houston')
,(124, '2018-04-24', 'Ralph', 'City'               ,'Hilton')
,(124, '2018-04-24', 'Ralph', 'Rating'             ,'Yellow')
,(124, '2018-04-24', 'Ralph', 'Comments'           ,'Decent')
,(124, '2018-04-24', 'Ralph', 'TransportationMode' ,'Van')

select ReportNumber, Datecreated, 
 max(case when Question='City'               then Answer else '' end) as City,
 max(case when Question='Hotel'              then Answer else '' end) as Hotel,
 max(case when Question='Rating'             then Answer else '' end) as Rating,
 max(case when Question='Comments'           then Answer else '' end) as Comments,
 max(case when Question='TransportationMode' then Answer else '' end) as TransportationMode
from @tmp 
group by ReportNumber, Datecreated
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I updated the question. The original table has just one more column that I added now. So there is a Question column and Answer column with values respect to each entry in Question column. The data comes from a view.

Comment: @Naphstor thank you for the clarifications, I updated my answer according to the new specifications